# Non-iterable value self.hand is used in an iterating context

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, blackjack

I'm working on a Discord bot that can be used to play blackjack (Python). The following code is supposed to calculate the values ​​of the respective hands:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, id=''):
        self.id = id
        self.hand = None
        self.status_text = ''
        self.bet = 0
        self.value = 0
        self.score = 0
        self.wins = 0
        self.no_response = 0
        self.request_leave = False
        self.playing = False

    def calculate_value(self):
        """Calculates value of player's hand"""
        if not self.hand:
            return 0
        num_aces = 0
        total_value = 0
        for card in self.hand:
            if pydealer.const.DEFAULT_RANKS['values'][card.value] == 13:
                num_aces += 1
                total_value += 11
            elif pydealer.const.DEFAULT_RANKS['values'][card.value] >= 10:
                total_value += 10
            else:
                total_value += int(card.value)

        while num_aces > 0 and total_value > 21:
                total_value -= 10
                num_aces -= 1
        return total_value
```

Unfortunately I get at

```
for card in self.hand:
    if pydealer.const.DEFAULT_RANKS['values'][card.value] == 13:
       num_aces += 1
       total_value += 11
```

the error Non-iterable value self.hand is used in an iterating context is displayed.
I hope someone can help! Greetings and thank you very much.

Comment: you are trying to iterate over self.hand which is initialized to None. You cannot iterate over None datatype.

Comment: what error is thrown exactly? This sounds like a pylint error, not a runtime error

Answer (score 0):

Your `self.hand` is initialized to be `None`.
So do make sure your `self.hand` gets set to an iterable object before you run stuff with it.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I ran into this recently, too, so in case anyone else does:

Assuming this is the pylint `E1133:not-an-iterable` error, you just need to give `self.hand` a type: `self.hand: list | None = None`. You're correctly checking `if not self.hand` before iterating, too, so mypy should also be satisfied.